# Graph in blender

Tags: modeling, scripting

Is it possible to plot a graph in blender from a formula using python, suitable for printing on A4; and if so, could someone point me in the direction of a tutorial?

Comment: If you really need to get this flowchart out I would use a dedicated flowchart maker.

Comment: Would be good to say if the graph is 2D or 3D

Answer (score 5):

If you mean a *mathematical* formula, then the *add 3d function surface* addon sounds like it is exactly what you are looking for.  I believe it is included in blender by default, so all you have to do is enable it under *user preferences > addons > add mesh*.  Once enabled, there will be an option to add a 3d surface under the *add mesh* menu (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).  Then press <kbd>F6</kbd> (or go to the toolbar on the left side of the 3d view) and you can modify the parametric functions in u and v for x, y, and z.  The documentation for this addon can be found [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_3d_Function_Surface).